# How to subscribe to Observable in a Jasmine unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have some mock json data that I want to read in to some unit tests. I'm making this a utility so that other unit test files can use it. For example:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MockUtilsService {
     
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    loadData(): Observable<any[]> {
        // Read local json file for mock data
        return this.http.get<any[]>('./mock-data.json');
    }
}
```

And then in the unit test:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [MockUtilsService]
    }).compileComponents();

}));

it('retrieve data', () => {
    
    const service = TestBed.get(MockUtilsService);
    service.loadData().subscribe(data => {
        expect(data).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

When I run the test, I see the error: 'retrieve data' has no expectations.'

I don't know if the loadData() method is not getting called, or if there's some kind of async problem where the test finishes before the subscribe method is called.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the test finishes before the subscribe method is called. Take advantage of the `done` callback that Jasmine provides allowing you to specify when the test has completed and you have finished your assertions.

```
it('retrieve data', done => { // add done as an argument here
    
    const service = TestBed.get(MockUtilsService);
    service.loadData().subscribe(data => {
        expect(data).toBeDefined();
        done(); // allow the test to come inside of this subscribe and then call done telling Jasmine you are done with your assertions.
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're performing an asynchronous operation so you need to run the test in async space. Update the test with `fakeAsync` and `tick` functions.

```
it('retrieve data', fakeAsync(() => {
    const service = TestBed.get(MockUtilsService);

    service.loadData().subscribe(data => {
        expect(data).toBeDefined();
    });
    tick();
}));
```